# Convert data frame to list of lists by row

Tags: converting, r

I am rewriting some old code where I take a dataframe in `r` and convert it using the `tidyverse` packages to a list of lists, where each element is one row of the original dataframe - which is itself a list with each column an element.

My previous function achieved it like so:

```
library(tidyverse)

feat <- function(coords, height = 20, vjust = 75,  fill = "orange"){
  inst <- purrr::flatten(purrr::by_row(coords, ..f = function(x) 
    rec <- list(type = "rect", 
                x = as.numeric(x[1]), 
                y = vjust, 
                width = as.numeric(x[2]-x[1]),
                height = height, 
                fill = fill), 
    .labels = FALSE))
  return(inst)
}
```

However `by_row()` has been depreciated from the `purrr` package and so I would like to rewrite it. This is my attempt:

```
feat2 <- function(coords, height = 20, vjust = 75,  fill = "orange"){
  inst <- coords %>% 
    mutate(type = "rect", 
           x = as.numeric(start), 
           y = vjust, 
           width = as.numeric(end-start),
           height = height, 
           fill = fill) %>%
    select(-start, -end) %>% 
    mutate(count = 1:n()) %>%
    nest(-count) %>%
    select(-count) %>% 
    mutate(data = map(data, ~ flatten(.x))) %>% pull()
  return(inst)
}
```

which does the job but I feel there should be a quicker, more elegant way to achieve this. Do you have any ideas on that aspect?

Here is an example data set:

```
coords <- structure(list(start = c(126, 433, 603, 1604), end = c(327, 495, 
644, 1831)), .Names = c("start", "end"), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = "data.frame")
```

and the desired output:

```
result <- list(structure(list(type = "rect", x = 126, y = 75, width = 201, 
    height = 20, fill = "blue"), .Names = c("type", "x", "y", 
"width", "height", "fill")), structure(list(type = "rect", x = 433, 
    y = 75, width = 62, height = 20, fill = "blue"), .Names = c("type", 
"x", "y", "width", "height", "fill")), structure(list(type = "rect", 
    x = 603, y = 75, width = 41, height = 20, fill = "blue"), .Names = c("type", 
"x", "y", "width", "height", "fill")), structure(list(type = "rect", 
    x = 1604, y = 75, width = 227, height = 20, fill = "blue"), .Names = c("type", 
"x", "y", "width", "height", "fill")))
```

Comment: Note that `by_row` has been migrated to `purrrlyr` and `purrrlyr::by_row` doesn't seem to be deprecated (though I'll admit the tools in `purrrlyr` seem to be left "aside" of the rest of the tidyverse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also asked this question over on the Rstudio community forums where user mgirlich provided this answer:

```
feat4 <- function(coords, height = 20, vjust = 75, fill = "orange") {
  coords %>%
    # transmute keeps only the columns specified, so there is no need to
    # deselect start and end afterwards
    transmute(
      type = "rect",
      x = as.numeric(start),
      y = vjust,
      width = as.numeric(end - start),
      height = height,
      fill = fill
    ) %>%
    purrr::transpose()
}
```

It is slower than the answer by @minem but the use of the `transpose()` function was new to me so I'll post it here.

Answer (score 2):

without any external packages:

```
feat3 <- function(coords, height = 20, vjust = 75,  fill = "blue"){
  xx <- apply(coords, 1, function(x) {
    list(type = "rect",
         x = as.numeric(x[1]), 
         y = vjust, 
         width = as.numeric(x[2] - x[1]),
         height = height,
         fill = fill)
    }
  )
  return(xx)
}

all.equal(feat3(coords), result)
# [1] TRUE
```

Benchmarks:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  feat3(coords),
  feat2(coords), unit = "relative"
)
# Unit: relative
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
# feat3(coords)   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   100  a 
# feat2(coords) 315.8261 297.2919 254.5025 258.7822 248.2652 286.9575   100   b
```

Comment: It's somewhat undesirable that `apply` first converts all the data to characters. It also forces you to use `x[1]` and `x[2]` to access specific columns, so you lose code readability a bit... I would suggest you build a data.frame `x` then do `unname(do.call(Map, c(list, x)))` to convert to a list of list. It's not nearly as fast but it is more robust and maintainable. In fact, the op might want to define `df_to_lol <- function(df) unname(do.call(Map, c(list, df)))` so he can use it within tidyverse, e.g., `mutate(...) %>% df_to_lol`.

Comment: @flodel It sounds that you should write a separate answer...

Comment: There are not a lot of people posting answers in the [r] group (thanks for joining and welcome). I prefer we help each other improve our answers than get into a competition for best answer.